# groovy list api creating new lists versus modifying current list

Tags: collections, groovy, immutability

Just could  not fathom why the groovy list api would have classes of methods that

a) allow modification of current list

b) return a new list,

e.g.

```
aList-['Hello','World']

// modifying a list
aList.set(2,'Modifying') //will modify aList itself, i.e. aList=['Hello','World','Modifying'

//create a new list without modifying self
aList.plus(1,'Worlds')   //aList is not modified, although this statements creates a new list: ['Hello','Worlds','Modifying']
```

My question is: why wouldn't the authors of Groovy stick to a standard, i.e. either have completely immutable collections so that all methods would either return new list instances without modifying the current collection instance, OR allow for methods such as 'plus' to modify the current collection. It seems a little un-intuitive to have two standards on this.

Answer (score 1):

Groovy wraps around Java and allows you to call existing Java methods.

So `set` is a [Java method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-) that manipulates the underlying list.  Therefore in Groovy, it just calls this method and you mutate the list.

`minus`, `plus` and `left-shift` are Groovy additions, so in the case of lists, they are written to not mutate the original lists.

When it comes to Maps however,`left-shift` DOES mutate the map, but I guess this is just something you have to remember.

Comment: Okay.. I guess the same could be said about traditional Java, although it beats me to figure out why have both these approaches. The reason this strikes me because of my experience with another experimental language where all collection were immutable objects.

Comment: Groovy isn't an experimental language built from first principles.  It's a language with one foot firmly in the Java API